# Missing whitespace between literal and alias at in bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT job_id 
FROM user_job fb 
WHERE extract(date from timestamp) BETWEEN extract(Date from 2021-03-17)
```

and I get this error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:137]

Comment: You have **one** opening parens, but **two** closing parens, after your `BETWEEN` .... and the string literal for the date isn't in single quotes

Answer (score 6):

BigQuery automatically recognizes well-formatted dates depending on the context.
In your case your query can be simplified in

```
SELECT
    job_id
FROM
    user_job
WHERE
    `timestamp` BETWEEN "2021-03-17" AND "2021-03-31"
```

The most important here are the quotes: your dates must be inside single or double quotes, and here since "timestamp" is a BigQuery function, you need to specify its a column name by using the back quotes ``
(or use an alias as you did but not necessary, actually the back quotes are not necessary either -BQ understands- but it's cleaner)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put datetimes into `DATETIME 'xxxxx'`:

```
SELECT job_id 
FROM user_job fb 
WHERE extract(date from fb.timestamp) BETWEEN extract(Date from '2021-03-17T14:26:56') and extract(Date from '2021-03-31T14:26:56')
```

Comment: its working with date time: i want to use date: extract(Date from '2021-03-17') and extract(Date from '2021-03-31')

Comment: hmm... you can just use `DATE '2021-03-17'` instead... like `BETWEEN DATE '2021-03-17' and DATE '2021-03-31'`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error , only code 400

It turns out the database had a name starts with a digit
So in this case the name of the database need to quoted:

Example:
If the database name is "**1**Test"
Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM 1Test.table1
```

It should be :

```
SELECT * FROM `1Test.table1`
```